# How do you change the opacity of an image in MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, opacity

I see you can change brightness and contract but is there a way to just change opacity?

As I have an image that I want to make the background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want use image as page background, then better is use as watermark.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051896401033.aspx (out-of-date?)

Link: [Insert-change-or-remove-background-colors-images-or-text-in-a-Word-2007-document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-change-or-remove-background-colors-images-or-text-in-a-Word-2007-document-98b2464f-83a3-4276-bdff-466d1d4f0993?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Steps to Turn a picture into a background or watermark

On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Background group, click Watermark.

Click Printed Watermark.

Click Picture watermark, and then click Select Picture.

Select the picture that you want, and then click Insert.

Select a percentage under Scale to insert the picture at a particular size

Select the Washout check box to lighten the picture so that it doesn't interfere with text.

The picture that you selected is applied as a watermark to the entire document.

Answer (score 4):

In Office 2003 there is a setting called Washout.

1. In the Microsoft Office document or file that contains the clip you want to wash out, click the clip.
2. On the Picture toolbar, click the *Format Picture* button [image].
3. Select the *Picture* tab.
4. Under *Image Control*, select *Washout* from the *Color* dropdown list, and then click *OK*.

In Office 2007, it looks like they got rid of the washout feature and added Recolor.

Answer (score 4):

In Microsoft Office Word 2010, you could set the recolour option to washout after selecting a picture and it will be transparent.

I think this also works in Microsoft Office Word 2007.

Answer (score 3):

Word 2010 semi-transparent picture workaround

1. Draw a solid rectangle
2. Right-click on it select *Format Picture*.
3. In *Format picture*, select the *Fill* tab.
4. In *Fill* tab, select *Picture or texture fill*, then click the *File* button.
5. Select your picture. Then set the transparency using the slider at the bottom of the *Fill* tab.

Answer (score 1):

i wound up just changing it in a photo editing program and reimporting it into word

Answer (score 1):

The washout in 2010 isn't actually transparency/opacity.  For instance if you overlay that image on top of something else, you won't see anything through it.  It's just a lighter image.  It would work fine as a watermark in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer gave me the idea to try MS Powerpoint.

- Open a new slide, select background options, select insert an image as the background and use transparency option to fade the background.
- Now go to snipping tool (it's an accessory with MS Office) and copy the slide as a PNG image.
- You can now insert your faded image into whatever document you are working on and overlay your text or whatever over the top.

If you want your image to be completely transparent, then you will need to use the set transparency option in MS Powerpoint first (search for instructions on this on google) and then follow the above instructions.